# D3 line chart data not aligned proper on x axis

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to create d3 line chart using v4 library. After spending some time and referring to examples I am able to create a line chart but data on x axis is propery not aligned. Data and label on x-axis are not in sync. [image: refer chart generated] Below is the source code for the chart:

```js
var data = [{ "month": "Jan", "volume": "33" }, { "month": "Feb", "volume": "12" }, { "month": "Mar", "volume": "41" }, { "month": "Apr", "volume": "16" }, { "month": "May", "volume": "59" }, { "month": "Jun", "volume": "38" }, { "month": "Jul", "volume": "21" }, { "month": "Aug", "volume": "25" }, { "month": "Sep", "volume": "30" }, { "month": "Oct", "volume": "47" }, { "month": "Nov", "volume": "5" }, { "month": "Dec", "volume": "20" }];

    var margin = { top: 50, right: 50, bottom: 50, left: 50 }
  , width = window.innerWidth - margin.left - margin.right
  , height = window.innerHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scaleBand()
          .range([0, width])

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
          .range([height, 0]);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

x.domain(data.map(function (d) { return d.month; }));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) { return d.volume; })]);


var line = d3.line()
    .x(function (d, i) { return x(d.month); })
    .y(function (d) { return y(d.volume); })
    .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX)

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

svg.append("path")
    .datum(data)
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", line);


svg.selectAll(".dot")
    .data(data)
  .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("class", "dot")
    .attr("cx", function (d) { return x(d.month) })
    .attr("cy", function (d) { return y(d.volume) })
    .attr("r", 5);
```

```css
.line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #ffab00;
    stroke-width: 3;
}
.dot {
    fill: #ffab00;
    stroke: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<body>
</body>
```

I am stuck with this as I have little knowledge of D3 library. Thanks in advance.

Same kind of question is also asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43478761/d3-shift-ticks-to-align-with-axis) and solution given there does not show the month name on x-axis. I also have requirement to show month name on x-axis. its showing .00 value on x-axis. [working jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/pm7gLn2u/)